# Session Userdata Type not works in particular function in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use this code in home function it get the usertype and works nice.

```
function home()
{

    $type = $this->session->userdata('type');
    if($type == "admin")
    {
    $this->load->view('index');
    }
    else if($type == "QA" || "SC" || "CDC")
    {
    $this->load->view('aindex');
    }
}
```

But when I use same code in jobsheet function it's not working. Code below

```
function jobsheet()
{
    $type = $this->session->userdata('type');
    $this->load->model('Ipss_model');

    $var1['job'] = $this->Ipss_model->AllJobSheet();
    $var2['division'] = $this->Ipss_model->AllDivision();
    $var3['tItem'] = $this->Ipss_model->transactionItem();

    $data = $var1 + $var2 + $var3;

    if($data['job'] != NULL )
    {
        if($type ==  "SC" || "CDC")
            {
            $this->load->view('jobsheet',$data);
            }
        else if($type == "admin" || "QA" )
            {
            $this->load->view('jobsheetQA',$data);
            }
    }

    else
    {
    $this->load->view('jobsheetEmpty',$data);
    }

}
```

Please help me about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check your condition with `$var1` not with `$data` `if($var['job'] != NULL )`

Comment: I already try  if($var1['job'] != NULL )  this one but not working.

Comment: you cac check NULL by using isset() `if(isset($var1['job']) && $var1['job']!="" )`

Comment: I try this one also not working.

Comment: `print_r( $var1)` paste what is the result of it????

Comment: It's show all data whatever I mentioned in query.

Comment: Please paste the value of `$type` ???

Comment: It's show the type of user perfectly.

Comment: can you please paste the value of `$type` and `print_r( $var1)`  ??

Comment: For all type user it shows first view for admin and QA also.

Comment: How can I show you this huge value for print_r( $var1) ?

Comment: just paste   between ``!!!

Comment: SCArray ( [job] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [JID] => 4 [jdate] => 2015-06-25 14:50:57 [BID] => 83 [jquantity] => 500 [com_status] => N [com_status_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [prn_info] => yes [prn_info_date] => 2015-06-25 [release_status] => released [cng_status_date] => 2015-06-29 15:25:24 [username] => 0            Here first word SC is user type. I write this comand print_r ($type); print_r($var1);

Comment: Just check with `if($type ==  "SC" || $type ==  "CDC")`

Comment: And `if(!empty($data)){if($type == "SC" || $type == "CDC")}`

Comment: Thanks for that now it works nice. Give this into answer not comment. I will take it as right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check weather array is empty or not you can use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). Also change your `||` condition like below.

So you condition would be

```
if(!empty($data))
    {
        if($type ==  "SC" || $type =="CDC")
            {
            $this->load->view('jobsheet',$data);
            }
        else if($type == "admin" || $type == "QA" )
            {
            $this->load->view('jobsheetQA',$data);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check your array() before using it in if condition 
with -:

> ```
> echo "<pre>";
> print_r($data);
> die();
> ```

Comment: I check it. It show lots of data beautifully. But not working below condition.

Comment: This should be a comment I think.